# Questions about Ebook torrents sources

Tags: discussion

Is it on topic to ask on Ebooks StackExchange "What is the good p2p (torrents) sources for ebooks and magazines/periodicals and manga and alike?"?

Answer (score 1):

This would be considered off topic for this site. For more information on what is on/off topic, you can check out our [help center](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).